# Tiling fixed-size rectangles to cover a given set of points

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

The problem - given a list of planar points `[p_1, ..., p_n]` and the dimensions of some rectangle `w, h`, find the minimal set of rectangles `w, h` that cover all points (edit - the rectangles are not rotated).

My inital solution was:

- find the bounding-box of all points
- divide the width and height of the bounding-box by the `w, h` of the given rectangle and round the number up to get the number of instances of the rectangle in `x` and `y`
- to further optimize, go through all rectangles and delete the ones that have zero points inside them.

An example in Python:

```py
def tile_rect(points, rect):
    w, h = rect
    xs = [p.x for p in points]
    ys = [p.y for p in points]
    bbox_w = abs(max(xs) - min(xs))
    bbox_h = abs(max(ys) - min(ys))
    n_x, n_y = ceil(bbox_w / w), ceil(bbox_h / h)
    rect_xs = [(min(xs) + n * w for n in range(n_x)]
    rect_ys = [(min(ys) + n * h for n in range(n_y)]
    rects = remove_empty(rect_xs, rect_ys)
    return rects
```

How can I do better? What algorithm can I use to decrease the number of rectangles?

Comment: Would you consider integer programming? e.g. [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization)'s Python bindings

Comment: Do all of the rectangles in the set need to be arranged contiguous/connected?  In Graph terms, does the graph of rectangles have to be a [Connected Graph, or can it be a Disconnected Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Connected_vertices_and_graphs)?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I used OR-Tools in the past but how would I use it for tiling? I can convert the problem to integers if needed.

Comment: @cellepo the rectangles can either overlap or be completely disconnected. The only requirement is that all points are covered and that the rectangles have a fixed size.

Comment: Can the rectangles have any rotation? Also, is an approximate, rather than optimal solution acceptable?

Comment: @גלעדברקן The rectangles are not rotated, just shifted. An approximate solution is acceptable indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To discretize the problem for integer programming, observe that given a rectangle we can slide it in the +x and +y directions without decreasing the coverage until the min x and the min y lines both have a point on them. Thus the integer program is just the standard min cover:

```
minimize sum_R x_R
subject to
for every point p, sum_{R contains p} x_R >= 1
x_R in {0, 1}
```

where `R` ranges over all rectangles whose min x is the x of some point and whose min y is the y of some point (not necessarily the same point).

Demo Python:

```
import random
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp

w = 0.1
h = 0.1
points = [(random.random(), random.random()) for _ in range(100)]
rectangles = [(x, y) for (x, _) in points for (_, y) in points]
solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver("min cover", "SCIP")
objective = solver.Objective()
constraints = [solver.RowConstraint(1, pywraplp.inf, str(p)) for p in points]
variables = [solver.BoolVar(str(r)) for r in rectangles]
for (x, y), var in zip(rectangles, variables):
    objective.SetCoefficient(var, 1)
    for (px, py), con in zip(points, constraints):
        if x <= px <= x + w and y <= py <= y + h:
            con.SetCoefficient(var, 1)
solver.Objective().SetMinimization()
solver.Solve()

scale = 6 * 72
margin = 72
print(
    '<svg width="{}" height="{}">'.format(
        margin + scale + margin, margin + scale + margin
    )
)
print(
    '<text x="{}" y="{}">{} rectangles</text>'.format(
        margin // 2, margin // 2, round(objective.Value())
    )
)
for x, y in points:
    print(
        '<circle cx="{}" cy="{}" r="3" fill="none" stroke="black"/>'.format(
            margin + x * scale, margin + y * scale
        )
    )
for (x, y), var in zip(rectangles, variables):
    if var.solution_value():
        print(
            '<rect x="{}" y="{}" width="{}" height="{}" fill="none" stroke="rgb({},{},{})"/>'.format(
                margin + x * scale,
                margin + y * scale,
                w * scale,
                h * scale,
                random.randrange(192),
                random.randrange(192),
                random.randrange(192),
            )
        )
print("</svg>")
```

Example output:

[image]

Comment: I don't agree with this formulation.  A simple 2-point counter example can demonstrate that using above anchoring plan, 2 rectangles would be required, while one centrally placed rectangle could cover both points.

Comment: @AirSquid Could you be more specific?

Comment: I may have misinterpreted...  I need to mull this over.  I withdraw the critique!  :)

Comment: Can you explain the notation please? What does `x_R` mean? Also, do you suggest using the integer solver from or tools - MPSolver?

Comment: @gilad `x_R` is the variable corresponding to rectangle `R`. It's 1 if `R` is part of the solution and 0 otherwise. I added some Python code implementing my idea.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat This takes >10mins on my machine with just 500 points. Do you know how can I speed things up? Even at the cost of a worse solution (I will eventually need to run this over 50k points.

Comment: @gilad what's the maximum acceptable time to run it for 50,000 points?

Comment: @gilad Assuming an approximate solution is OK, various things to try, easiest to hardest: 1) set the MIP relative gap to >0 so that it doesn't waste time looking for the absolute optimal solution 2) do a coarse spatial partition that puts about 500 points in each partition, then cover each one separately 3) if a lot of that time is spent in the presolving phase (turn on debug output to get a sense), use a better algorithm to enumerate candidate rectangles that doesn't produce so many duplicates 4) there might be a column generation approach, but I'd have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an approximate, rather than optimal solution is acceptable, how about a routine generally like:

```
Until no points are left:
  (1) Find the convex hull of the remaining points.
  (2) Cover each point/s on the hull so the
      covering rectangles extend "inward."
      (Perhaps examine neighbouring hull points
      to see if a rectangle can cover more than one.)
  (3) Remove the newly covered points.
```

Clearly, the orientation of the covering rectangles has an effect on the procedure and result. I think there is a way to combine (1) and (3), or possibly rely on a [nested convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_layers), but I don't have too much experience with those.

Answer (score 0):

This is can be transformed into a mostly standard set cover problem. The general steps are as follows, given n points in the plane.

- First, generate all possible maximally inclusive rectangles, of which there are at most n^2, named R. The key insight is that given a point p1 with coordinates (x1, y1), use x1 as the leftmost bound for a set of rectangles. For all other points p2 with (x2,y2) where x1 <= x2 <= x1+w and where y1-h <= y2 <= y1+h, generate a rectangle ((x1, y2), (x1+w, y2+h)).
- For each rectangle r generated, count the points included in that rectangle cover(r).
- Choose a subset of the rectangles R, s, such that all points are in Union(r in s) cover(r)

Now, the tricky part is that last step. Fortunately, it is a standard problem and there are many algorithms suggested in the literature. For example, combinatorial optimization solvers (such as SAT solvers, MIP solvers, and Constraint programming solvers) can be used.

Note that the above re-formulation only works if it is ok for rectangles to cover each other. It might be the case that the generated set of rectangles is not enough to find the least set of rectangles that do not overlap.